# Convert Brackets to Links Java

Tags: java, regex

I am writing a little android application using java. I have some text in which some words are in brackets. I want to convert them to links.

```
* [[my text]] 
* [[my text]] 
* [[my text]] 

To

* <a href="http://my text">my text</a>
* <a href="http://my text">my text</a>
* <a href="http://my text">my text</a>
```

I know a very little about Regex please help.

Comment: You do have to work through some RegEx tutorials.  Otherwise how can you possibly understand any solution you are provided with?

Comment: I have just tried to simply replace the text like:  result = result.replace("* [[", "\<a href=\"");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Little theory

Regex allows us to create something which we call [capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). They allow us to use only some part of matched text.

For example regex like `X(a+)(b+)Y` will try to find text like `XaabbbY` and will store

- series of `a` in group 1
- series of `b` in group 2.

We can do few things with that part of matched text stored in these groups. We can

1. simply get (and later print) it using `Matcher#group(x)`

But we can also reuse it in

2. regex with `\x` (where `x` represents group number) like `([a-z])\1` is regex which will find only pairs: `aa` `bb` ...  `yy` `zz`,
3. replacement with `$x` (`x` here also represents group number).

---

#### Your case

In your case it looks like you want to replace text between `[[` and `]]` with `<a href="http://(thatText)">(thatText)</a>`

To find text between `[[` and `]]` we can use regex `\[\[(.*?)\]\]`

- we surrounded `.*?` with parenthesis so we could reuse only part between brackets
- by adding `?` to `*?` we made `*` quantifier [reluctant](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) which means instead of finding maximal match like

  ```
  foo [[a]] bar [[b]] baz
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ```

  it will try to find minimal match like:

  ```
  foo [[a]] bar [[b]] baz
      ^^^^^
                ^^^^^
  ```

So we can reuse part from group 1 in replacement via `$1`. In other words we can replace entire `[[...]]` part with something like `"<a href="http://$1">$1</a>"`

Which leads us to solution like

```
yourText = yourText.replaceAll("\\[\\[(.*?)\\]\\]", "<a href=\"http://$1\">$1</a>");
```

Answer (score 2):

For matching use `\[\[([\s\S]+?)\]\]`, then for replacing use `<a href="$1">$1</a>`

http://regexr.com/3d3g5

[image]